# Using Rserve with java and want to calculate t.test. Cant get result back to java

Tags: java, r, rserve

Got this problem with a formula in Rserve. I tried with `double` and `int` but that didn't work either. It's a block of text that I want back from R. Describing the CI. But the result doesn't seem to come back to the java application. I have tried the commands in R and there they work. Have no idea why it's not working. 
I got this code:

```
package rservedem;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;


import java.util.Scanner;
import org.rosuda.REngine.*;
import org.rosuda.REngine.Rserve.*;
/**
 *
 * @author Carl
 */
public class RserveDem {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RConnection connRserve;

         Scanner inputStream = null;
                    try {
                        inputStream = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("C:/vikt-fore_data2Update.csv")); //läser in data från fil


                }
                     catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        System.out.println("Filen hittades inte! Stänger av...");
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
     inputStream.useDelimiter(",");


     int vikt;

                    double [] memberArray = new double[157];
                    for (vikt = 0; vikt < memberArray.length; vikt++) {



                                memberArray [vikt] = Double.valueOf(inputStream.next());

                    }

        try {


       connRserve = new RConnection();
       connRserve.assign("memberArr", memberArray);
       String toRserveForProcessing = "t.test(memberArr);";


       System.out.println("Den skapade strängen som skickas till Rserve " + toRserveForProcessing);

       String summan = connRserve.eval(toRserveForProcessing).asString();
       System.out.println ("Svaret från rserve " + summan);

   }
    catch(RserveException ex)
    {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
   catch (REXPMismatchException ex)
   {
       System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
   }
        catch (Exception e)
{
    System.out.println("Seomthing went wrong, but it's not Rserve: " +e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
}
    }

}
```

I have tried to search the error message but couldn't find out what it means. Would be really helpful to get some ideas on how to do the command and get the result back in the output window in the java application. 
And I get this error:

```
attempt to access org.rosuda.REngine.REXPGenericVector as String
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

In `connRserve.eval(toRserveForProcessing).asString();` try `connRserve.eval(toRserveForProcessing).toDebugString();` instead.

As the exception states you're trying to use a vector as a string, if you would like to access the result expression you have to access it type appropriately. In this case you should be able to call `asList()` and then access each item in the vector with the accessor methods.